# Switch views - UIViewController to UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have made a very simple Navigation based app (UIViewController). The view has a single button on the Main RootViewController.

Next, I made 2 classes: TabOneViewController, TabTwoViewController. All good. I then created a new Class TabBarViewController. I opened up the NIB file and dropped on a ``UITabBarController onto it. The two tabs it creates in it by default were assigned (respectively) to my TabOne and TabTwo view controllers.
strong text
Then in my TabBarViewController, I made an IBOutlet for a UITabBarController, synthesized it etc etc. I linked it up in Interface builder via the "files owner".

In the RootViewController, I linked the button to my "pushView" method, and in this pushView method, I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction) pushView {
    TabBarViewController *controller = [[TabBarViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

The end result is it DOES push a view, but I cannot see the tab bar at the bottom, let alone any of the pages I've added to the controller.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I link it in IB?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if that's allowed.. because you already have one tabBarController as rootViewController, and you dropped one more tabBarController as first tab controller, tabs ll overlap, considering amount of real estate you have on your iPhone, it make sense to not allow a tabViewController inside another

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to allocate your view controller with your nib:

```
TabBarViewController *controller = [[TabBarViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNibName" bundle:nil];
```

Secondly, in IB, click the UITabBarController and go to the identity inspector and make sure you select your custom class.  That said, unless you are overriding or adding some functionality you probably don't need the custom class at all, simply use a UITabBarController directly:

```
UITabBarController *controller = [[UITabBarController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNibName" bundle:nil];
```